# Binding an ObservableCollection to multiple listviews not working

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm new to programming and am having trouble figuring out how to get my ObservableCollection working on two different listviews across two different Windows in WPF. I think the problem is how I implemented my ObservableCollection, with the main culprit being this line here as shown in the SoundsWindow class:

```
ViewModel vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;
```

This is how my listview displays my items added through:

```
vm.AddFile(fi.Name, file, 1);
```

The issue being that this does not update the other listview on the other window and neither is anything stored.

Heres my ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        SoundFiles = new ObservableCollection<SoundFile>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public void AddFile(string fileName, string fileLocation, int groupID)
    {
        SoundFile soundfile = new SoundFile { FileName = fileName, FileLocation = fileLocation, GroupID = groupID };
        SoundFiles.Add(soundfile);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SoundFile> soundfiles;
    public ObservableCollection<SoundFile> SoundFiles
    {
        get { return soundfiles; }
        set
        {
            soundfiles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SoundFiles");
        }
    }
}
```

SoundsWindow class:

```
public partial class SoundsWindow : Window
{
    public SoundsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();

    }

    private void loadFileBtn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        ofd.Filter = "MP3 Files (*.mp3)|*.mp3";
        var result = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            ViewModel vm = this.DataContext as ViewModel;

            foreach (String file in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);                   
                vm.AddFile(fi.Name, file, 1);
            }               
        }
    }
```

My SoundFile class:

```
public class SoundFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="FilesList1" ItemsSource="{Binding SoundFiles}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="379" Margin="10,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}" Width="230"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Location" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileLocation}" Width="320"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Group" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GroupID}" Width="40"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

For testing purposes the other window is a copy of SoundsWindow so that shouldnt be a problem.

As I pretty much have no idea what I'm doing iv checked about everything but am pretty sure the culprit is my implementation of how i add and store things in ObservableCollection. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Obviously `this.DataContext = new ViewModel();` is called in both windows. You do hence have two view model instances. Create a single one outside the Window constructor and pass it to the DataContext of both Windows.

Comment: Can we see the code you use to load the window please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please show me how I would do that @Clemens . Thanks for the help.

Comment: One simple approach would be a static property in the ViewModel class, e.g. `public static ViewModel Instance { get; } = new ViewModel();`. Then assign the instance to a Window's DataContext by `DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks @Clemens you're a legend.